# English certificate for postdoc in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, ielts

I am applying for a postdoc in the UK. I hold an academic IELTS certificate. Does anyone know is that enough for a Tier-2 visa?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-o-approved-english-language-tests

Comment: Thanks Jessica. On that form, we do not see any information about the type of IELTS. I am wondering whether academic IELTS is enough for both university and visa purposes or not...

Comment: I took the two lines of IELTS to be the two forms they accepted. But see https://www.ielts.org/what-is-ielts/ielts-for-migration/united-kingdom

Answer (score 9):

Being a Tier 2 migrant here myself, I can confirm that IELTS Academic exam is accepted for Tier 2 applications. The general rules are [here](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/knowledge-of-english).

However, a word of caution is needed. UKVI has recently changed the list of [approved test providers](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/635698/Approved_Secure_English_Language_Tests_and_Test_Centres.pdf), and IELTS franchise seems to split into "IELTS" and "IELTS for UKVI" providers. Only "IELTS for UKVI" providers are approved for immigration purposes. The exams are essentially the same, it is only the level of screening, security and scrutiny which is different.

It is **not clear** to me whether the  IELTS certificates issued before the split are still accepted by UKVI. Many people assume that they should because the laws can not be applied retrospectively, but IANAL. I would like to know the answer, too.

Comment: I am at this phase and I am planning to take an IELTS for UKVI General Training for a postdoc position. Do universities specify which test their post-docs must pass or is it a visa issue?

Comment: If you received a job offer for a postdoc post, it specifies all conditions you should met. If the only condition is to get a visa, then you "only" need to meet UKVI language requirements. Typically, people take IELTS for UKVI (Academic) test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

A couple of sentences for people who might be in my situation:

In order to get Tier-2 visa, you have to take part in IELTS exam. The one which is acceptable for this purpose is IELTS for UKVI and the other tests would cause failure to your application.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything beyond what Dmitry said.